# After upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04 from 14.04 can't get grub to boot

Tags: boot, grub2, upgrade, amd-graphics

The upgrade went especially well [infinitely better and less problematic than 12.04 to 14.04 [which was a multi-WEEK hell]. However, after it completed and I rebooted...nothing! but a black terminal that said only 'Grub Repair>', not a usual TTY screen.

I have used Grub Repair Disk and tried everything I can think of over 25 times.....still it won't boot. [Here is the log of the last try.](http://paste.ubuntu.com/16044800)

Please, if anyone can see the problem [!and the/an answer!] let me know! Thanks! I see some indications I am not the only one with this or similar problem. I had NO major error messages during the upgrade...so am surprised. The minor ones were only messages that I'd have to reinstall x or y minor programs. No errors were recorded upon completion, and it said it had upgraded successfully...but had it?!

Question. I use an AMD graphics board and used to use Catalyst. I'm aware this is no longer available, but should have been replaced by Linux drivers [which are listed as excellent for my board]....but could this be the problem, and if so, how to know or fix?

The very last thing I can think of possibly causing a problem is that I chose GDM3 rather than GDM or LightDM. Is there a problem with this?

If I were to use a live disk to attempt a fix, what would I do, and in what order? I did not try, as I thought the Boot Repair Disk did anything the live disk could [assuming, as I so far have, it was a grub problem alone]. Perhaps I'm wrong. Many thanks.

I know there will be some replies suggesting a 'clean install'. I have my reasons to avoid that unless death is the only other alternative. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Ha second time in 5 minutes I have recommended this only for different issues.... If its a grub issue, use http://www.supergrubdisk.org/ to scan and repair the boot partition. (and I doubt a year later its helpful)